# pylint balks on reference to __package__

Tags: python, import, pylint

I'm using `__package__` in setup.py to refer to the top-level name of the package it's supposed to test, build, install, etc.. However, pylint objects:

```
Module 'mian.mian' has no '__package__' member
```

This works fine in `ipython`:

```
from mian import mian as package
package.__dict__
...
 '__package__': 'mian',
```

Is pylint doing the right thing here, ignoring PEP 366's "When the import system encounters an explicit relative import in a module without __package__ set (or with it set to None), it will calculate and store the correct value"? If so, what do I need to change?

Workaround: Use `package.__name__.rpartition('.')[0]` instead of `package.__package__`.

Comment: If you're really trying to fix everything that pylint complains about, you'd have an awful lot of work for nothing. And your program will only get worse. But you might file a bug report.

Comment: which version of pylint are you using (hint: include the output of pylint --version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now a ticket on Pylint's tracker: http://www.logilab.org/ticket/73668